# Why there is no iPad mini 3, opposite to iPad mini 2 on apple website?

Tags: ipad, apple-store

On the root site you can buy iPad mini 2 and iPad mini 4.

[image]

Why there is no iPad 3? Is there any reason for this? iPad mini 2 is better than 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[On September 9, 2015, the iPad Mini 3 was discontinued and was replaced by the iPad Mini 4.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_Mini_3)